# What is the probability of getting a full house in a 7 card poker hand

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

I'm trying to calculate the probability of getting a full house in a 7 card poker hand. This is obviously the number of 7 card full house hands divided by $\binom{52}7$. To try and calculate the number of 7 card full houses, I tried this strategy:

1. chose two ranks $\binom{13}2$
2. get two cards of the first rank $\binom{4}2$
3. get three cards of the second rank $\binom{4}3$
4. chose two cards from the remaining 47 cards $\binom{47}2$

When I do this, I calculate $\frac{2,023,632}{133,784,560}$, which equals about $0.015$, or $1.5\%$. However, [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability) says I should be getting about 2.6%. Why is my answer so wrong?

Thanks!

-Diego

Comment: order of the ranks matters (kings on jacks is different from jacks on kings) - so 13*12 ways to choose ranks. The last 2 cards must be chosen from 46 (one card would give you 4 of a kind for a best hand)

Comment: Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $7$-card poker, the best five cards are selected.  Therefore, you can obtain a full house in three ways:

- A three of a kind, a pair, and two singletons
- A three of a kind and two pairs
- Two three of a kinds and a singleton

Also, you failed to distinguish between the rank of the three of a kind and the rank of the pair.  By selecting two additional cards at random, you created the possibility of a four of a kind, which is not permitted.  The first error made your outcome too small.  The second error would have led to an over count had you not made the first error, particularly since the four of a kind could have been paired with a pair or a three of a kind.

*A three of a kind, a pair, and two singletons*:  There are $13$ ways to select the rank of the three of a kind, $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to select three of the four cards of that rank, $12$ ways to select the rank of the pair, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select two cards of that rank, $\binom{11}{2}$ ways to select the ranks of the two singletons, and $4$ ways to select a card from each of those ranks.

> There are $$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{11}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2$$ such hands.

*A three of a kind and two pairs*:  There are $13$ ways to select the rank of the three of a kind, $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to select three of the four cards of that rank, $\binom{12}{2}$ ways to select the ranks of the two pairs, and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select two cards from each of those ranks.

> There are $$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{2}\binom{4}{2}^2$$ such hands.

*Two three of a kinds and a singleton*:  There are $\binom{13}{2}$ ways to select the ranks of the three of a kinds, $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to select three of the four cards of each of those ranks, $11$ ways to select the rank of the singleton, and $4$ ways to select a card of that rank.

> There are $$\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{3}^2\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{1}$$

Since these three cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of favorable cases is found by adding the three results.  Dividing that sum by $\binom{52}{7}$ yields the desired probability.

**Addendum:**  As aschepler pointed out in the comments, it is not possible to combine a full house with a straight or a flush with only seven cards, so the cases above are indeed exhaustive.

Comment: Nice. The one missing detail: $7$ cards is too few to have a hand which contains both a full house and a straight (or royal) flush, so we can ignore those. For a hand with $8$ cards, those would need some subtractions.

Comment: @aschepler  That is a good point.   I credited you with that observation.   The best five cards requirement makes calculating the probabilities for a seven card hand trickier than those of a five card hand.

Comment: @aschepler  In a $7$-card hand that includes a full house, you can obtain at most four different ranks: the rank of the three of a kind, the rank of the pair, and up to two additional ranks with the remaining two cards.

Comment: @aschepler  A flush requires five cards of the same suit which are not of consecutive ranks, which means you would need at least five cards of different ranks in that suit for a flush.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Wow, dumb mistake! Sorry, you're right.

Comment: This is really helpful!  Thanks for taking the time to write this.

Comment: Great answer and of course correct. One question though for my understanding. Why can we not combine part 1 and 2 (Trips and a Pair, Trips and Two Pairs) with this formula (using Excel notation for the combinations): COMBIN(13,2)*COMBIN(4,3)*COMBIN(12,1)*COMBIN(4,2)*COMBIN(44,2). The first part matches but then my - wrong - formula says we pick one of the remaining 12 ranks, times 6 suit combination and the remaining two cards could be any of the 44 remaining cards which are not part of the Trips nor the Pair.

Comment: @Gecko  If you meant to write $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{44}{2}$, the issue is that you count each hand with two pairs twice, once for each way you designate one of the two ranks from which pairs are drawn as the rank from which a pair is drawn.

Comment: @Taussig I meant to write exactly what you wrote and thank you for the explanation, it makes sense now. Will search for more posts by you - the best way to learn about combinatorics :-).

Answer (score 1):

In the calculations in the Wikipedia article you linked to, it has ${4\choose3}^2$ for the case that you have, say, three aces, and three twos, and ${4\choose 2}^2$ for the case that you have, say, three aces, two kings, and two jacks, as well as ${4\choose 3}{4 \choose 2}{4\choose 1}^2$ for the case that you have, say, three aces, two kings, one jack, and one queen.

I checked this numerically by the way, here is the number of full houses in a run of 100,000,000 random 7-card hands:

```
2629860 100000000 2.63
```